# Conversion of synchronous methods with Action/Func parameters to asynchronous

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've looked around and can't find this question asked anywhere.

Given the following method:

```
public TOut WithThing<TOut>(Func<T, TOut> func)
{
  var thing = CreateThing();
  thing.DoSomething();
  return func(thing);
}
```

I have an equivalent `void` method which wraps the above for when I don't want to return a value (it's calling `WithThing<bool>` really and just discarding the result):

```
public void WithThing(Action<T> action)
{
  WithThing(x =>
  {
    action(x);
    return false;
  });
}
```

I'm trying to create asynchronous versions of the above methods because "Thing" has synchronous and asynchronous methods.

I *think* the equivalent of the first method is:

```
public async Task<TOut> WithThing<TOut>(Func<T, Task<TOut>> func)
{
  var thing = CreateThing();
  await thing.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  return await func(thing).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I didn't think I'd need the `ConfigureAwait`'s but Visual Studio is suggesting them. Is this correct? Why do I need the `ConfigureAwait`'s?

If the above code is correct, then I'd guess the signature for the equivalent that doesn't return a value would be `public async Task WithThing(Func<T, Task> func)`. What would the body be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware that using `ConfigureAwait(false)` is contextual and you must be aware of when not to use it. Refer to the [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) and [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming - Configure Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#configure-context).

Your guess on the [return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types) is correct.

I would avoid wrapping too much as it adds allocations and delegate invocations.

For the sync part I would do something like this:

```
public TOut WithThing<TOut>(Func<T, TOut> func)
{
  Someting();
  return func(thing);
}

public void WithThing(Action<T> action)
{
  Someting();
  action(x);
}

private void Someting()
{
  var thing = CreateThing();
  thing.DoSomething();
}
```

and for the async:

```
public async Task<TOut> WithThing<TOut>(Func<T, Task<TOut>> func)
{
  await SometingAsync();
  return await func(thing).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task WithThing(Func<Task> action)
{
  await SometingAsync();
  await action(thing).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private void SometingAsync()
{
  var thing = CreateThing();
  await thing.DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into the use of `ConfigureAwait`. Do you have an answer for whether the my method body for the conversion is otherwise correct? I'm also still having trouble writing the method which wraps it to just return a Task (in the same way as the second of my first two methods).

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I mentioned, I'll look into `ConfigureAwait` but I'm curious, why you choose to use it in your example?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Your last method `private void SometingAsync()` won't compile. you cannot `await` inside a method that is not marked `async`.

Comment: Because it has no need for a synchronization context. So, I don't need to be jumping in and out of it.